# Abel's continuity theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $\{b_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ is a bounded sequence. Is it true that
$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1-}(1-x)\sum_{t\geq 0} b_tx^t=b$ if and only if $\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=0}^{T-1}b_t=b$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*Lemma* (Cesaro) Let $(a_n),(b_n)$  be sequences of numbers such that $b_n>0$, set $A(t)=\sum a_nt^n$ and suppose $B(t)=\sum b_nt^n$ converges for $|t|<1$ and diverges at $1$, and $a_n/b_n\to s$. Then $$\lim_{t\to 1^{-}}\frac{A(t)}{B(t)}=s$$

Let's use this to prove a direction of your theorem. Note that if we let $b_n=n+1$, and take $a_n$ as $s_n=\sum_{i=0}^n a_n$, we have that $$\frac{A(t)}{B(t)}=\frac{\sum_{n\geqslant 0}s_nt^n}{\sum_{n\geqslant 0}(n+1)t^n}=\frac{(1-t)^{-1}\sum_{n\geqslant 0} a_nt^n}{(1-t)^{-2}}=(1-t)\sum_{n\geqslant 0} a_nt^n$$

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I have a related question again. Now suppose $\frac{1}{T_k}\sum_{t=0}^{T_k-1}a_t=a$ converges for a subsequence $\{T_k\}$. Can we show there exists a sequence $x_n\uparrow 1$ such that $\lim_n (1-x_n)\sum_{t=0}^\infty a_t x_n^t=a$?